# How to increase cache performance when computing t-test of large data matrix

Tags: c++, caching

I've managed to trace down the bottle necks of my bioinformatics program. One of them is the computation of [t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test) for a large data matrix, a 40K*30 (sometimes the column count could be close to 200) matrix. The rows of the data matrix are genes, and the columns are samples of two groups to be compared against each other.

```
const std::size_t gene_count(40000);
std::vector<double> t_score_vector(gene_count, 0.0);

for(std::size_t i=0; i<gene_count; ++i){
    // do regular t-test of the two groups for row i of the data matrix
    t_score_vector[i] = t_test_score; // this single assignment decreased performance by 50%
}
```

Now a data matrix of this size is impossible to fit in cache entirely, 8*40000*30 ~ 9MB, regular PC's have 8MB L3 cache max. To make things worse, writing to the vector that stores the t-test for all genes slows things down a lot.

Is there a better design, to make a better use of cache?

Comment: Are you sure the vector write slows your code down because of the write, or could it simply prevent your compiler from optimizing away the entire loop? Is there any other value produced from this loop?

Comment: @Leeor Yes, the row's of the matrix is used for calculating something--a scalar quantity called t--one for each row. And they must be stored in someplace, here it is stored in a vector. Hence the vector is of the same size as the row count of the matrix.

Comment: But what was your baseline for performance comparison? If you just removed the write, your compiler may have eliminated the entire loop.

Comment: @Leeor, I see your point. But here is the observation. I've tried to eliminate the assignment at the last line, and compute some dummy thing at the end, without using it. Of course the compiler warned, but the run time is actually observably longer than the case without the dummy and the assignment, though shorter than when the assignment was there. So my guess is that the loop isn't probably optimized away entirely. Of course to figure out exactly, assembly is necessary. But I don't how to do that yet.

Comment: Is this under Linux? You can use `objdump -d` over your binary (or better - an unlinked object file) and look for the function.